# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester' AND PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, scikit-learn, error-handling

I am trying to use sklearn in jupyter notebook, but when I use `import sklearn` (`sklearn` is already installed) and/or `from sklearn import linear_model`, it gives me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'
```

When I try to upgrade numpy and pip, it gives me this error:

```
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

When I try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in both jupyter notebook and the command prompt, I get the following message.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\basecommand.py'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: run the command prompt/powershell as admin

Comment: is there anyway to bypass this? no one available with the admin creds.